# Variables format in SAS proc import

Tags: import, format, sas

When importing an excel file into SAS, I find that the import is not being done properly due to wrong variables'format.

The table trying to import look like this:

```
ID  Barcode
1   56798274
2   56890263
3   60998217
4   SKU89731
...
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.test
        DATAFILE= "D:\Barcode.xlsx" 
        DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
 RANGE="Sheet1$"; 
 GETNAMES=YES;
 MIXED=NO;
 SCANTEXT=YES;
 USEDATE=YES;
 SCANTIME=YES;
 RUN;
```

What happens is that column "Barcode" has best12. format and therefore cases as ID=4 get a missing value ('.') because they originally had both characters and numbers.

Since it is not possible to change the format of a variable in a proc step how can I import the file correctly, and **only using SAS editor**?

EDIT:

Another option that does half the work and it might give some inspiration is dynamically changing the format of the variable by importing through a data step:

```
libname excelxls Excel "D:\Barcode.xlsx";

data want;
set excelxls.'Sheet1$'n (DBSASTYPE=(Barcode='CHAR(255)'));
run;
```

With the above code I force SAS to import the variable in the format I want (char), but still missings are generated for values as in ID=4.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you have `mixed=NO`. Change this to `mixed=YES` and SAS will check a sample of the observations to see if there are any non-numeric characters in the variables - if it finds one then it will specify the variable as character.

Take a look at the link [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003103761.htm) for more information:

Comment: Hi Bendy, thanks for your answer. I have tried that already, but by changing the option to `MIXED=YES` the only thing changing is that I get an extra note in the log file: `NOTE: Data source is connected in READ ONLY mode.`
. So I still get missing values.

Comment: Add in the `guessingrows=` as @DWal suggests in his answer...you can specify how many of the initial records it should check for non-numeric characters

Answer (score 2):

You could convert to a csv (or maybe xls?) file and either:

1. use the `guessingrows=` option to increase the number of rows SAS uses to determine type.
2. If you want complete control of the import: copy the data step code that `proc import` puts in the log and paste into your program. Now you can modify it to read the data exactly as you want.

Comment: Hi DWal thanks for your addition. I have tried your suggestion but I got an error: `guessingrows=10000;
          ------------
          180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper
order.` From a bit of searching online it turns out that the `guessingrows=` option is not compatible with .xlsx files, and since I cannot alter the type of the file I want to import this is no longer an option I think.

Comment: @Noob_Strider You should do the second thing that DWal suggests, and take the code it creates, then modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: To be honest I didn't quite understand the 2nd solution. Could you please explain a bit more thoroughly? When running the initial `proc import` then the log produces the following: `PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.test
DATAFILE= "D:\Barcode.xlsx"
DBMS=excel REPLACE;
RANGE="Sheet1$";
GETNAMES=YES;
MIXED=YES;
SCANTEXT=YES;
USEDATE=YES;
SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;

NOTE: WORK.test data set was successfully created.
NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           1.19 seconds
      cpu time            1.01 seconds
`. How can I modify that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess SAS doesn't put the generated code for xlsx files. I don't import Excel files often.